# How to get location one time when getLastLocation time fix is old

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-location

I am using google play services location api. I want to be able to get the current location of the user once and not listen for updates. I am currently using getLastLocation to get the users last known location. Then i am checking on the time fix and if the time fix was more than a minute ago then i would like to requestLocationUpdate but only once meaning that i want to get the current location and not listen for updates.

I have seen many tutorials on getting only the last known location and many tutorials on listening for location updates but i cannot seem to find the best practice for querying the users location in the moment (for example when a button is clicked)

I have google play services location api working in the app and onConnect is also being invoked correcty. The following is what i have in onConnect method

**pusedo code:**

```
if location.getTime() < 1000 * 60 then 
//get the coordinates
else
//TODO query for current user location
```

What should i be placing in the TODO section to query the users location?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement full logic for receiving location. Here is the documentation https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html

Comment: I already did so. Just wondering what is the best way to get a location updates and stop when it is accurate enough for my application to use.

Comment: I need to get one set of coordinates and use that to query an api. I dont want to listen for location changes. Once i receive an accurate fix i want to use it to query an api. This is not a run tracking app, its more like geotagging on a picture.

Comment: simply call  `LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, this);` in first `onLocationChanged()` callback

Comment: Yes, i was thinking about that as well. I wanted to know what be the best time to call that method. I was thinking i will call it when the accuracy of the fix is in a certain range.

Comment: in every callback you receive new Location object and you can check its accuracy